# ошибка 404 при post запросе

Tags: python, requests, http-status-code-404

только начинаю в библиотеке requests, но нужно сразу сделать некоторую практическую вещь. В данном случае мне нужно на адрес "https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/{personGroupId}" отправить данные. Вместо location нужно вставить регион пользователя (в моём случае - westcentralus), а в конце название группы лиц, которая создаётся по адресу.
Когда же я исполняю свой код, мне выдаёт, что страница не найдена и я ума не приложу, почему

```
import requests, json
key='7820231cbf9d4e7294ec86cd472e0e95'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key}

url_create_group = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/test1'

params = {'personGroupId' : 'test1'}

#json_str = {
 #   'name' : 'group_test',
  #  'userData' : 'this group created for my studying.'
#}
#req_body = json.dumps(json_str)
response = requests.post(url_create_group, params=params,  
headers=headers)#, req_body)

print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Я совсем упустил, что вы хотите создать группу. Тогда вам нужен метод `PUT`.

В [документации](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395246) сказано, что нужно использовать  `HTTP GET` метод, а не `HTTP POST`

```
response = requests.get(url_create_group, params=params, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Ответ:

```
200
{'personGroupId': 'test1', 'name': 'group1', 'userData': 'user-provided data attached to the person group.'}
```

API принимает дополнительные данные в JSON. С помощью requests это можно сделать так (отдаете словарь, он будет конвертирован в JSON):

```
data = {
    'name': 'group_test',
    'userData': 'this group created for my studying.'
}

response = requests.put(url_create_group, 
                        json = data,
                        params=params, 
                        headers=headers)
```

Или конвертируете в JSON сами и посылаете:

```
import json


data = {
    'name': 'group_test',
    'userData': 'this group created for my studying.'
}

response = requests.put(url_create_group, 
                        data = json.dumps(data),
                        params=params, 
                        headers=headers)
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь)

Comment: А не подскажете, как прикрепить к запросу ту часть, которая идёт после "#"?

Comment: я посмотрел, дело в том, что get нужен для просмотра информации о группе. Для добавления группы нужен PUT, но здесь он выдаёт мне, что тело запроса неверное, так что и хочу спросить

Comment: Дополнил ответ, попробуйте эти способы.

Comment: круто, большое спасибо

Comment: Все нормально отправляется?

Comment: вроде да, спасибо

Comment: Хорошо. Обратите внимание на то, что в вопросе вы показали ваш ключ API. Наверное стоит отредактировать вопрос и скрыть ключ. Еще лучше будет сгенерировать для себя новый, если у вас есть такая возможность.

Comment: не волнуйтесь, он пробный и длится неделю)